# can't see ffmpeg on phpinfo after install

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, xampp

I have installed the **Ffmpeg** extension on **Xampp** (I have windows 10-pro 64x-but I use 32x xampp) and Apache gives me this error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

and I can't see `ffmpeg` in the `phpinfo()` output.